# undefined is not an object (evaluating pray.findIndex)

Tags: javascript, react-native

when i run the code i get this error,

undefined is not an object (evaluating 'pray.findIndex')]

```
const [pray, setPray] = useState([]);
const fetchPray = async county => {
 const url4 = '-' + county;
 console.log(url4);
 fetch(url4)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => setPray(json))
.then(pray => {
  let index = pray.findIndex(d => d.MiladiTarihKisa === date);
  let selectData = pray[index];

  setVakitGunes(selectData.Gunes);
  setVakitImsak(selectData.Imsak);
  setVakitOgle(selectData.Ogle);
  setVakitIkindi(selectData.Ikindi);
  setVakitAksam(selectData.Aksam);
  setVakitYatsi(selectData.Yatsi);
  setGunTurkce(selectData.MiladiTarihUzun);
})
.catch(error => console.log(error))
.finally(() => setLoading4(false));
};
```

Comment: `setPray(json)` returns void, so the next `.then()` block will get undefined instead of `pray`

Comment: @SergeySosunov how can i fix it?

Comment: Just remove that line entirely and in next .then after it insert setPray(pray); at the first line.

Comment: @SergeySosunov if u avaliable could you show on code , thank you sergey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to `.then(json => setPray(json))` line. It is an equivalent to

```
.then(json => {
  const res = setPray(json);
  return res;
})
```

And `setPray` or any other setter-function from `useState` returns undefined (void). So the next `.then` just after it will get `undefined` instead of what you were expecting.

Fix:

```
const fetchPray = async (county) => {
  const url4 = "-" + county;
  console.log(url4);
  fetch(url4)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((pray) => {
      setPray(pray);
      let index = pray.findIndex((d) => d.MiladiTarihKisa === date);
      let selectData = pray[index];

      setVakitGunes(selectData.Gunes);
      setVakitImsak(selectData.Imsak);
      setVakitOgle(selectData.Ogle);
      setVakitIkindi(selectData.Ikindi);
      setVakitAksam(selectData.Aksam);
      setVakitYatsi(selectData.Yatsi);
      setGunTurkce(selectData.MiladiTarihUzun);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    .finally(() => setLoading4(false));
};
```

Comment: [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'selectData.Gunes')]
if i make it like i said i get this error now :/

Comment: @sweoguzhan That is the next issue, not related to your original question :) That happened due to `pray.findIndex` returned `-1` due to item was not found with your search criteria. And array[-1] will return undefined. You should check what date you got in `pray` array, if it is an array at all and if it contains `MiladiTarihKisa` and if `date` object can be found there. Not much i can do without actual data. What you can do - add `console.log(pray, date);` just before `let index = pray.findIndex` call and check your data.